# The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FirebaseUser'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, firebase-authentication

Whenever i call this function ( _sendToServer) in an onPressed function i get this error.
**error: The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FirebaseUser'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [robic] lib\profile_page2.dart:117)**
how cam i solve this.

```
 _sendToServer(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
      _key.currentState.save();
      DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
      var data = {
        "name": name,
        "profession": profession,
        "message": message,
        "id": user.uid,
      };
      ref.child('node-name').push().set(data).then((v) {
        _key.currentState.reset();
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _autovalidate = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

```
onPressed: () {_sendToServer(FirebaseUser);},
```

Comment: here `_sendToServer(FirebaseUser)` you are passing only Type FirebaseUser...

Comment: so what should i write. i am actually wanting to get user id from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the Current user from FirebaseAuth

Try this instead

```
_sendToServer() async{
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
      _key.currentState.save();
      DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
      var data = {
        "name": name,
        "profession": profession,
        "message": message,
        "id": user.uid,
      };
      ref.child('node-name').push().set(data).then((v) {
        _key.currentState.reset();
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _autovalidate = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

call the function like this

```
onPressed: () {_sendToServer();},
```

don't forget to import FirebaseAuth

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change **FirebaseUser** in **onPressed(){_sendToServer(FirebaseUser)}** to **FirebaseUser()**

```
onPressed: () {_sendToServer(FirebaseUser());},
```